# como sumar dos objetos en java

Tags: java

tengo esta clase que manda dos objetos y deberia sumarlos y luego desplegarlos en forma de calendario pero la verdad estoy estudiando programacion y no se como hacer para que se sumen los dos objetos y aguardar el resultado en un tercero agradeceria su ayuda

```
Random ventaAleatoria = new Random();

       
      // Agregar ventas a las ventas citadinas y a las suburbanas
       ventasSubUrbanas.setEntrada(20);
       ventasCitadinas.setEntrada (10);
       
       // Sumar las ventas citadinas y las suburbanas dejándolas en ventas totales.
      ventasTotales.suma(ventasCitadinas);
      ventasTotales.suma(ventasSubUrbanas);
       
       // Imprimir las ventas citadinas
       System.out.println("Despliegue de las ventas citadinas");
       ventasCitadinas.despliegaCalendario2();
       
       // Dejar dos líneas
       System.out.print("\n \n");
       
       // Imprimir las ventas suburbanas
       System.out.println("Despliegue de las ventas suburbanas");
       ventasSubUrbanas.despliegaCalendario2();
       
       // Dejar dos líneas
       System.out.print ("\n \n");
       
       // Imprimir la suma de las ventas citadinas y suburbanas
       System.out.println("Despliegue de las sumas de las ventas");
       ventasTotales.despliegaCalendario2();
   
   }
}
}
```

y necesito sumar el contenido de estos objetos
ventasSubUrbanas.setEntrada(20);
ventasCitadinas.setEntrada (10);

tengo esta otra clase que recibe los datos

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class LibroRegistro {
    // Definición de los datos de la clase
    private int mes;                                 // mes del registro 
    private int anio;                                // año del registro
    private int[] entradas;                         // entradas en el libro del registro
    private GregorianCalendar calendarioDelRegisto;  // Clase Calendar incluida en Java
    

    /** **********************************************************************
     * Constructor de objetos de la clase registro
     *********************************************************************** */
    public LibroRegistro( int mes, int anio)
    {        
        
        // Registro del año
        this.anio = anio;
        
        // Registro del mes del año. Si el mes es inválido, se asume el mes de enero.
        if ((mes >= 1) && (mes <= 12)){
           this.mes = mes;
        }
        else {
           this.mes = 1;
        }
        
        // Definición del vector de las entradas
        int numeroDiasMes = this.getNumeroDiasDelMes();
        this.entradas = new int[numeroDiasMes+1];
        
        // Asignación del valor al calendario del registro
        calendarioDelRegisto = new GregorianCalendar(this.anio, this.mes - 1, 1);
        
    }
    
    public LibroRegistro() {
        
        calendarioDelRegisto = new GregorianCalendar();
        this.anio = calendarioDelRegisto.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        this.mes = calendarioDelRegisto.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

        int numeroDiasMes = this.getNumeroDiasDelMes();
        this.entradas = new int [numeroDiasMes + 1];
    }
    
    public void setEntrada(int valor) {

          for(int i=0 ; i <= getNumeroDiasDelMes(); i++){
                if(i==calendarioDelRegisto.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
                this.entradas[i]= valor;

            }
        }
        }

    // ***********************************************************************
    // Setters de la clase LibroRegistro
    // ***********************************************************************
    /**
     * Asigna el valor de la entrada para el libro de registro mensual, dado el día
     * 
     * @param      dia, valorEntrada         día del mes y valor de la entrada para ese día
     * @return     nada 
     */
   
    public void setEntrada(int day, int valorEntrada){

        for(int i=0 ; i <=getNumeroDiasDelMes(); i++){
            if(i==day){
                this.entradas[day]= valorEntrada;
            }
        }
     
    }
    
    // ***********************************************************************
    // Getters de la clase LibroRegistro
    // ***********************************************************************    
    /**
     * Sirve como interfaz para proporcionar el valor de la entrada
     * 
     * @param      dia                  día del mes para el que se quiere conocer la entrada
     * @return 
     * @return     valorEntrada o -1    valor de la entrada del día especificado o -1 por ser número de día erróneo
     */
    public int getEntrada(int dia){
         //System.out.printf ("    %4d                          ", diaDeLaSemana(dia));
        return this.entradas[dia];
    }
  
    /**
     * Sirve como interfaz para proporcionar el mes correspondiente 
     * al libro de registro
     * 
     * @param      nada
     * @return     mes                  número del mes correspondiente 
     *                                  al libro de registro
     */
    
  
    
    public int getMes()
    {
        return this.mes;
    }
    
    /**
     * Sirve como interfaz para proporcionar el año correspondiente 
     * al libro de registro
     * 
     * @param      nada
     * @return     anio                  número del año correspondiente al libro de registro
     */
    public int getAnio()
    {
       return this.anio;
    }
    
    /**
     * Sirve como interfaz para proporcionar número de días del mes del libro de registro
     * 
     * @param      nada
     * @return     día                  número de días correspondientes al mes del libro de registro
     */
 
    public int getNumeroDiasDelMes(){
         
       int numeroDias = 0;
     
            switch(mes){
                case 1:
                case 3:
                case 5:
                case 7:
                case 8:
                case 10:
                case 12:
                    numeroDias=31;
                    break;
                case 4:
                case 6:
                case 9:
                case 11:
                    numeroDias=30;
                    break;
                case 2:
     
                    Date anioActual=new Date();
                    if(esAnioBisiesto(this.anio) == true ){
                        numeroDias=29;
                    }else{
                        numeroDias=28;
                    }
                    break;
     
            }
     
        return numeroDias;
          
    }
    
    
    public void despliegaCalendario2 () {
         int[][] Matriz;
            int[][] MatrizDia;

            Matriz= new int [7][6];
            MatrizDia= new int [7][6];





            int contz = 1;


            for(int conty = 0; conty < 6 ;conty++){
                for(int contx = 0; contx <7 ;contx++){
                   if(contz <= getNumeroDiasDelMes()){
                        if(contx == diaDeLaSemana(contz)){


                       Matriz[contx][conty] = getEntrada(contz);
                       MatrizDia[contx][conty] = contz;

                        contz++;
                        }
                        else{
                            Matriz[contx][conty] = 0;
                            MatrizDia[contx][conty] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

     

    /*   contz = 1;
            for(int conty = 0; conty < 6 ;conty++){
                for(int contx = 0; contx <7 ;contx++){ 

                  System.out.print(MatrizDia[contx][conty]+"        "+Matriz[contx][conty]+"       ");
                  contz++;

                }
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(""); 
            }*/
            
           
            contz = 1;
            System.out.println ("Domingo Lunes Martes Miercoles Jueves Viernes Sabado");    
            for(int y = 0; y < 6 ;y++){
                  System.out.print("|");
                 for(int x = 0; x <7 ;x++){ 
                    System.out.print (MatrizDia[x][y]+" "+Matriz[x][y]+"");
                    if (y!=Matriz[x].length) System.out.print("\t");
                  }
                  System.out.println("|");
                }
    }
        
    // ***********************************************************************
    // Definición de los métodos facilitadores de la clase
    // ***********************************************************************
    /**
     * Indica si el año del libro de registro es bisiesto o no
     * 
     * @param      anio
     * @return     Verdadero o Falso    
     */
    public boolean esAnioBisiesto(int anio)
    {
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        boolean esBisiesto = false;
        if (calendar.isLeapYear(anio)) {
            esBisiesto = true;
        }
        return esBisiesto;
    }
 
        private int diaDeLaSemana(int dia){
            
            calendarioDelRegisto.set(this.anio, this.mes- 1, dia);
            int diaDeLaSemana = calendarioDelRegisto.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
            return diaDeLaSemana;
        }

            void suma(LibroRegistro libroreg) {
        
             
            
            
}
  
    }
```

pero no se que deberia ir en mi void suma para que pueda sumar los objetos
ya que apenas estoy aprendiendo a porgramar y es una de mis tareas y ando atorado en esa parte

Comment: Supongo que `ventasTotales` es un objeto de la clase `LibroRegistro`, pues es en esa clase donde veo que tienes un método `suma()`. Pues bien, podrías modificar `LibroRegistro` haciendo lo siguiente: 1. Dotarlo de un miembro que podrías llamar `total` (sería del tipo `int`,  o `long` o `Decimal` o `BigDecimal`, depende pues no queda claro si lo que se va a computar es la totalidad de ventas o valores monetarios ¿? ; 2. Cambiar el parámetro de `suma`, en vez de recibir un objeto del tipo `LibroRegistro` recibiría un parámetro del tipo que haya declarado a `total`;...

Comment: ... 3. Dentro del método, incrementar el valor de `total`, sumándole el valor que haya recibido en parámetro.